# Creating a dummy column based on column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have datetime column in Dataframe.

I want to create a dummy column in the same dataframe such that
for 1st row of A value is equal to 1st row of datetime column + 15 minutes
2nd of A row is equal to value of 1st row of A
3rd of A row is equal to value of 3rd row of A

than for 4 row again value is equal to 4th row of datetime column +15 minutes
so and so forth
I wrote this loop, f is the main dataframe

```
m15 = []
i=0,
while i < len(f):
    m15[i] = f['Datetime'][i]+ dt.timedelta(minutes=15),
    m15[i+1] = m15[i]
    m15[i+2] = m15[i]
    i=i+3
```

I am getting error **'<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'**

how to solve the problem

Desired output

```
Datetime                       Dummy
2020-16-12 09:15:00            2020-16-12 09:30:00
2020-16-12 09:20:00            2020-16-12 09:30:00
2020-16-12 09:25:00            2020-16-12 09:30:00
2020-16-12 09:30:00            2020-16-12 09:45:00
2020-16-12 09:35:00            2020-16-12 09:45:00
2020-16-12 09:40:00            2020-16-12 09:45:00
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data - e.g. 5 rows and expected output?

Comment: for 3rd of A row is equal to value of 3rd row of A. please read3rd of A row is equal to value of 1st row of A

Comment: yes, I know, but I cannot test, because I have no your data.

Comment: Buddy you need to provide some form of sample data to work on.

Comment: attached the image hope you all can see

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Problem is I cannot copy data from picture, so is possible add data in text form?

Comment: Hi there. I want to add some information to the error message. You are writing `i=0,`. This creates a tuple with one element which is equal to this assignment`i = (1,)`. This you can not compare with an integer. And this is why you get this type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First dont use loops, because here is possible vectorized alternative.

You can add `15 minutes` to column, then replace each 2nd and 3th value to `NaT` and use `ffill` for forward filling missing values.

Here is used helper array `np.arange(len(df))` for groups, but if default `RangeIndex` is possible change it by `df.index`.

```
#if necessary
#df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')


df['New'] = (df['Datetime'].add(pd.Timedelta(minutes=15))
                           .mask(np.arange(len(df)) % 3 != 0)
                           .ffill())
print (df)
             Datetime                Dummy                 New
0 2020-12-16 09:15:00  2020-16-12 09:30:00 2020-12-16 09:30:00
1 2020-12-16 09:20:00  2020-16-12 09:30:00 2020-12-16 09:30:00
2 2020-12-16 09:25:00  2020-16-12 09:30:00 2020-12-16 09:30:00
3 2020-12-16 09:30:00  2020-16-12 09:45:00 2020-12-16 09:45:00
4 2020-12-16 09:35:00  2020-16-12 09:45:00 2020-12-16 09:45:00
5 2020-12-16 09:40:00  2020-16-12 09:45:00 2020-12-16 09:45:00
```

Another idea:

```
df['New'] = (df['Datetime'].add(pd.Timedelta(minutes=15))
                           .groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3)
                           .transform('first'))
```

Comment: this just adds more and more columns to dataframe

Comment: Thanks a ton done. I cannot upvote you since I an new to stack